# Why is there a confusing gap in the list of attribute form encodings in the Dwarf 4 specification

Tags: debugging, standards, dwarf

In the table of attribute form encodings table (Figure 21 page 161) in the specification for DWARF4 ([here](http://www.dwarfstd.org/doc/DWARF4.pdf)) there is a gap. The entries go

```
Form name            Value   Class
DW_FORM_ref_udata    0x15    reference
DW_FORM_indirect     0x16    (see Section 7.5.3)
DW_FORM_sec_offset   0x17    lineptr, loclistptr, macptr, rangelistptr
DW_FORM_exprloc      0x18    exprloc
DW_FORM_flag_present 0x19    flag
DW_FORM_ref_sig8     0x20    reference
```

Note the value counts from 0x19 to 0x20, not 0x1a as might be expected. A pleasing trap for unwary developers! I wondered if this the gap was left intentionally (perhaps to allow for future expansion) or by mistake but I can't find an answer one way or the other?

Comment: May want to ask this on DWARFs [public comment](http://dwarfstd.org/Comment.php) page.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Good idea. I've asked and I'll update here if / when I get a response.